# Mail sending functionalities in Suite CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Can you please list down the mail sending functionalities provided by Suite CRM.
Eg: When the user is assigned to an Account, the user getting a mail notification. But when the user is removed from the account (In the Account 'Edit' page, Change the user by clicking the 'X' button next to the 'Assigned to', then the user is not getting mail that he has been removed.)
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello i did not work on suitecrm i worked on  sugarcrm so i am answering your question according to suitcrm.

**1.** You have to create a email template for it first.An example of Account module send email on status change .

You can add after save logic_hook to account module.

**1)** Add following line in your `custom/modules/Accounts/logic_hooks.php`

```
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'send ', 'custom/modules/Accounts/send_email.php', 'accountSendEmail', 'send_email');
```

**2)** Create a php file named `"send_email.php"` in `"custom/modules/Accounts/" folder.`

**3)** Create email template form email module and get 36 char ID of it.

**4)** Write following code in `custom/modules/Accounts/send_email.php` file.

```
class accountSendEmail{
    function send_email(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
    if (empty($bean->fetched_row)) {
       require_once("include/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
       require_once("modules/Administration/Administration.php");
       require_once("modules/EmailTemplates/EmailTemplate.php");
       $emailtemplate = new EmailTemplate();
       $emailtemplate = $emailtemplate->retrieve("email_template_id");
       $emailtemplate->parsed_entities = null;
       $temp = array();
       $template_data = $emailtemplate->parse_email_template(
       array(
           "subject" => $emailtemplate->subject,
           "body_html" => $emailtemplate->body_html,
           "body" => $emailtemplate->body
           ),
           'Accounts',
           $bean,
           $temp
           );
       $email_body = $template_data["body_html"];
       $email_subject = $template_data["subject"];
       $admin = new Administration();
       $admin->retrieveSettings();
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail->IsSMTP();
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->Host = $admin->settings['mail_smtpserver'];
       $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
       $mail->Port = 465;
       $mail->Username = $admin->settings['mail_smtpuser'];
       $mail->Password = $admin->settings['mail_smtppass'];
       $mail->From = $admin->settings['notify_fromaddress'];
       $mail->FromName = $admin->settings['notify_fromname'];
       $mail->Subject = $email_subject;
       $mail->Body = from_html($email_body);
       $mail->IsHTML(true);
       $mail->AddAddress('your@email.address');
       if (!$mail->send()) {
          $GLOBALS['log']->info("Mailer error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
          $is_send = 'notsend';
       } else {
         $is_send = 'send';
       }
     }
  }
}
```

2. Please check this link it help you :

[Link 1](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/21983)

[Link 2](https://johndopenotes.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/sugarcrm-send-email-with-attachment-using-sugarphpmailer-class/)

[Link 3](https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/03/01/howto-send-an-email-inside-sugar-thru-code/)

3. Above steps are to send emails through code , i sugar there is new concept which is **PRocess**  you can send email on process also.

[Process](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.7/Ent/Application_Guide/Processes/)

I think this will help you it help me a lot regarding the emails.

Comment: Thanks Amitesh. Let me try this. As of now the suitecrm is sending mail notification by default only when the user added to an account. But the mail notification is not sending when he has been removed from the account. So in the default mail sending functionalities of suitecrm, mail notification is not there for remove the user from an account? It can be implement only through custom mail? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
// require_once('phpmalier.php');
$mail = new SugarPHPMailer();
//
//                    $mail->setMailerForSystem();
//                    $mail->From = $focus->settings['notify_fromaddress'];
//                    $mail->FromName = $focus->settings['notify_fromname'];
//                    $mail->Subject = $subject;
//                    $mail->IsHTML(true);
//                    $mail->Body = $body;//$html_body;
//                    $mime_type = "application/pdf";
//                    $mail->AddAttachment($sugar_config['upload_dir'] . $file_name.'.pdf', $file_name, 'base64', $m`enter code here`ime_type);
//                    $mail->prepForOutbound();
//                    $mail->AddAddress($To_email);
                    //if (!$mail->Send()) {
                    //$GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Email for Cases# " . $bean->name . " is not sent. Please check Email id of the contact ");
                    //  }
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code. Also - most of your code is irrelevant, since it's commented.